# MediaRecorder "start failed: -22"

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to use MediaRecorder to capture example video.
Here is my code:

```
final Button btnRecord = findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {

            String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File dir = new File(storagePath);
            File videofile = new File(dir, "file.mp4");

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setOutputFile(videofile.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
            Snackbar.make(view, "success!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Snackbar.make(view, e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it fails with:

```
11-13 14:02:36.197 10174-10174/com.example.username.myapplication E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -22
```

I found -22 stands for "Invalid argument": http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno

I have following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

It also fails when executed in separated thread. I also tried to set non-default encoders and it didn't helped.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Have you tried Capturing videos section ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video ) ? Seems to need setCamera() etc. Also needs to set `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest.

Comment: You are right! This helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @noonespecial what changes you made? I am also getting same error start failed: -22 and tried all the way not getting over it. Can you help me please?