# Android Application using java which can record the video and audio with just one click of a button

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on a project which can record the video with just single click of a button. I am able to record the audio easily but when I try to record the video the app crashes with a RuntimeException: start failed -22. Please help me on this.

Below is my code. Thanks for support

activity_video_recorder.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recordButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Recording"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

VideoRecorderActivity.java

```
package com.pns.loginregisterapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class VideoRecorderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_recorder);

        Button recordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(view ->{
                VideoRecorder videoRecorder = new VideoRecorder();
                videoRecorder.startRecording();

                // Stop recording after 10sec
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(() -> videoRecorder.stopRecording(), 10000);
        });

        if (!hasPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPermissions() {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

VideoRecorder.java

```
package com.pns.loginregisterapp;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

public class VideoRecorder {

    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    public void startRecording() {
        if (isRecording) {
            Log.e("VideoRecorder", "Already recording.");
            return;
        }
        
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
//        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
//        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);


        String outputFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my_video.mp4";
        Log.e("TAG",outputFilePath);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFilePath);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            isRecording = true;
            Log.d("VideoRecorder", "Recording started.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("VideoRecorder", "startRecording() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        if (!isRecording) {
            Log.e("VideoRecorder", "Not recording.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            isRecording = false;
            Log.d("VideoRecorder", "Recording stopped.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("VideoRecorder", "stopRecording() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
Detailed Logcat

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (19819) for package com.pns.loginregisterapp ----------------------------
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
2023-09-20 14:18:06.268 19819-19819 zygote64                com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-09-20 14:18:07.033 19819-19819 AppCompatDelegate       com.pns.loginregisterapp             D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2023-09-20 14:18:07.077 19819-19819 FtBuild                 com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  getRomVersion mRomVer=4.0
2023-09-20 14:18:07.235 19819-19819 DecorView               com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  setWindowBackground mBackgroundPadding = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), mFramePadding = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), pkg = com.pns.loginregisterapp
2023-09-20 14:18:07.462 19819-19904 OpenGLRenderer          com.pns.loginregisterapp             D  HWUI GL Pipeline
2023-09-20 14:18:07.501 19819-19819 TouchMotionHandler      com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  handler onAttached
2023-09-20 14:18:07.582 19819-19904 Adreno-EGL              com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 11/14/18, f979681, I4e9dba44e5
2023-09-20 14:18:07.593 19819-19904 zygote64                com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2023-09-20 14:18:07.594 19819-19904 OpenGLRenderer          com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2023-09-20 14:18:07.594 19819-19904 OpenGLRenderer          com.pns.loginregisterapp             D  Swap behavior 1
2023-09-20 14:18:07.595 19819-19819 RenderThread            com.pns.loginregisterapp             W  type=1400 audit(0.0:582): avc: denied { search } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="sysfs" ino=22816 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_kgsl:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2023-09-20 14:18:07.596 19819-19904 Adreno-ES20             com.pns.loginregisterapp             W  <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
2023-09-20 14:18:07.598 19819-19904 Adreno-EGL              com.pns.loginregisterapp             W  <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2023-09-20 14:18:07.613 19819-19904 Adreno-EGL              com.pns.loginregisterapp             W  <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:612>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
2023-09-20 14:18:17.001 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  constructor
2023-09-20 14:18:17.003 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  doCleanUp
2023-09-20 14:18:17.003 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setListener
2023-09-20 14:18:17.003 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setClientName
2023-09-20 14:18:17.004 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setAudioSource(1)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.004 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  Call init() since the media recorder is not initialized yet
2023-09-20 14:18:17.004 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  init
2023-09-20 14:18:17.009 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setVideoSource(1)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.010 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setOutputFormat(2)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.011 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setAudioEncoder(3)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.012 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setVideoEncoder(0)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.015 19819-19819 TAG                     com.pns.loginregisterapp             E  /storage/emulated/0/my_video.mp4
2023-09-20 14:18:17.017 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  setOutputFile(57)
2023-09-20 14:18:17.018 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  prepare
2023-09-20 14:18:17.018 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             V  start
2023-09-20 14:18:17.371 19819-19819 MediaRecorder           com.pns.loginregisterapp             E  start failed: -22
--------- beginning of crash
2023-09-20 14:18:17.372 19819-19819 AndroidRuntime          com.pns.loginregisterapp             D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-20 14:18:17.377 19819-19819 AndroidRuntime          com.pns.loginregisterapp             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.pns.loginregisterapp, PID: 19819
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
                                                                                                        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.pns.loginregisterapp.VideoRecorder.startRecording(VideoRecorder.java:36)
                                                                                                        at com.pns.loginregisterapp.VideoRecorderActivity.lambda$onCreate$1(VideoRecorderActivity.java:26)
                                                                                                        at com.pns.loginregisterapp.VideoRecorderActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6319)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24955)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (19819) for package com.pns.loginregisterapp ----------------------------
2023-09-20 14:18:17.421 19819-19819 Process                 com.pns.loginregisterapp             I  Sending signal. PID: 19819 SIG: 9
```

I am trying to get both video and audio in a MP4 file but able to record only audio

Comment: Post complete stacktrace please of the exception.

Comment: Are you saying a video file is created?

Comment: @blackapps Yes the file is created

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The file can be created but what is its size? 0 bytes? As `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.` would imply that no recording is done. Can you play that file?

Comment: `the app crashes with a RuntimeException: ` Catch that exception and display a toast() to the user to inform.

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266765/mediarecorder-start-failed-22

Comment: `start failed: -22` find out what error code -22 means.

Comment: @blackapps The file size is 0 bytes only. And for the error code -22 I searched on internet a lot but not able to find anywhere.

Comment: @zomega Yeah but the answer is not there

Comment: Yes the answer is there and also the error code description for -22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ```
> >    String outputFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my_video.mp4";
> > ```

In Android 11+ devices your app cannot create files in root of external storage.

(You could have tried just to create that file yourself to see that it does not go).

Instead use one of the public directories on external storage that are already there like Movies of Videos. (have a look first which is available)

And try to create a file there yourself for a test.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using Android Oreo and my video file is created also.